# A formula to solve fractional powers- exponents?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

IS there a general formula with which i could solve exponential 'equations'?
When there is something like :
$$x^{1/2}=8$$

I can just look at it, and say that $x$ is $64$, because the power of $1/2$ is the square root of that number.

Now since I used to solve these easier ones just by looking at them, when I get something like:
$$x^{3/2}=2\sqrt{x}$$

I have problems solving it. Obviously this can be solved in the mind as well, but it just gets harder from here, so I would like to now the general formula, or solving process of these kind of equations.

Regards.

Comment: To write $\sqrt{x}$, write \sqrt{x} when you are in math mode.

Comment: get used to manipulating with the power-of-a-power rule. e.g.$$x^{3/2}=x^{\frac{1}{2}\cdot 3} = \bigg(x^\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^3 = \sqrt{x}^3$$

Answer (score 3):

Write $\sqrt{x}$ as $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$, then try to remove $x$ from the RHS.  Remember that $\frac{x^a}{x^b} = x^{a-b}$.  It can be a lot harder if there are also additive terms.

Comment: Thank you. So I should always  be able to find a common exponent, with different powers, and then solve the equations as linear or quadratic equation?

Comment: In this case you can just divide both sides by $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ to get $x=2$.

Comment: I know, but I mean generally I should/should be able to do that, if there is an  answer, right?

Comment: Yes, although it won't always lead to the answer, consider $x^{\frac{5}{2}} + x^{\frac{1}{2}} = 2$, this is an ["unsolvable" quintic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function), it has a solution actually but there's no way to represent it with standard operations.

Comment: Thank you. :) But that should be university level? Or its before that?

Comment: Just remember you divide by $x^{1/2}$ only when $x\neq0$. The case $x=0$ has to be considered separately; and it turns out it is one of the possible solutions of the equation.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$x^{3/2}-2\sqrt{x}=0$$
Now, let $y=\sqrt{x}$
$$\therefore y^3-2y=0$$
Solve for $y$ and substitute back at the end.

Answer (score 2):

There is no general formula to solve an equation with fractional exponet of the form
$$
ax^{\frac{m}{n}}+bx^{\frac{p}{q}}+c=0
$$

If $c=0$ we can find a solution because the equation becomes:
$$
ax^{\frac{m}{n}}=-bx^{\frac{p}{q}}
$$
that, for $x\ne 0$ is:
$$
\frac{x^{\frac{m}{n}}}{x^{\frac{p}{q}}}=\frac{-b}{a} \iff x^{\frac{m}{n}}x^{-\frac{p}{q}}=\frac{-b}{a}\iff x^{\frac{qm-pn}{nq}}=\frac{-b}{a}
$$
that gives:
$$
x=\left(\frac{-b}{a}\right)^{\frac{nq}{qm-pn}}=\sqrt[(qm-pn)]{\left(\frac{-b}{a}\right)^{nq}}
$$

With some care to the fact that, if we want that $x$ is a real number, the argument of the root have to be positive for an even radical index.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general formula for solving exponential equations.

Let's look at the two problems you posed.

In the first problem, we can square the square root to obtain the number.
\begin{align*}
x^{\frac{1}{2}} & = 8\\
(x^{\frac{1}{2}})^2 & = 8^2 && \text{square both sides of the equation}\\
x^1 & = 64 && \text{since $(x^a)^b = x^{ab}$}\\
x & = 64 && \text{since $x^1 = x$}
\end{align*}

In the second problem, we can write $\sqrt{x} = x^{\frac{1}{2}}$, then factor.
\begin{align*}
x^{\frac{3}{2}} & = 2\sqrt{x}\\
x^{\frac{3}{2}} & = 2x^{\frac{1}{2}} && \text{by definition}\\
x^{\frac{3}{2}} - 2x^{\frac{1}{2}} & = 0 && \text{subtract $2x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ from each side of the equation}\\
x^{\frac{1}{2}}(x^1 - 2) & = 0 && \text{factor and use $x^{a + b} = x^ax^b$}\\
x^{\frac{1}{2}}(x - 2) & = 0 && \text{since $x^1 = 1$}
\end{align*}
If a product is equal to zero, then one of the factors must be equal to zero.  Thus, 
\begin{align*}
x^{\frac{1}{2}} & = 0 & x - 2 & = 0\\
(x^{\frac{1}{2}})^2 & = 0^2 & x & = 2\\
x^1 & = 0\\
x & = 0
\end{align*}

The second problem can be done more simply if use the observation that $x^{\frac{3}{2}} = (x^{\frac{1}{2}})^3$, which is why Yagna Patel made the clever substitution $y = \sqrt{x} = x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ in order to obtain the equation $y^3 - 2y = 0$ from the equation $x^{\frac{3}{2}} - 2\sqrt{x} = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is take both sides to the original power  inverse e.g.

$$x^{\frac{1}{2}}=8\implies 
\big(x^{\frac{1}{2}}\big)^2=8^2=x=64\\
x^{\frac{2}{3}}=8\implies
\big(x^{\frac{2}{3}}\big)^{\frac{3}{2}}
=\big(8\big)^{\frac{3}{2}}\implies 
x^1\approx 22.63$$